# The norm and the angle of the complex number $\sqrt[3]{-1}\sqrt[6]{7}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I am learning the roots of unity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity). I want to express arbitrary complex number in radical form in terms of the norm and the angle to use the formula $e^{i\phi}=\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)$.  Consider $x^6=7$ that is not of the roots of unity form such as $x^6=1$. Now its solution is $x=\sqrt[3]{-1}\sqrt[6]{7}\in\mathbb C$: how to calculate the norm and the angle for $\sqrt[3]{-1}\sqrt[6]{7}$?

Comment: There are 6 solutions; not just 1. $\sqrt [6]7$ is obviously one with norm $\sqrt [6]7$ and angle 0. $\sqrt[3] {-1} =-1$ so the one you listed has angle $\pi$. What I think you are getting at is the six roots are $r\sqrt [6]7$ where $r $ are the six roots of unity. These solutions all have norm of $\sqrt[6]7$ and the angles are $i*2\pi/6$. Sammy Black has a more thorough and general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x$ in polar form:
$$
x = re^{i\phi}.
$$
Then the equation $x^6 = 7$ becomes
$$
r^6 e^{6i\phi} = 7e^{0}
$$
so
$$
r^6 = 7 \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad r = \sqrt[6]{7}
$$
and
$$
6\phi \equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi} \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad
\phi \equiv 0 \pmod{\tfrac{\pi}{3}}.
$$
The last condition is equivalent to being a cube root of $-1 = e^{i\pi}$.

Comment: And the markings for the complex roots are $\zeta_{6}^{1}$, $\zeta_{6}^{2}$, $\zeta_{6}^{4}$ and $\zeta_{6}^{5}$ because the angle is $\phi=\frac{2\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$. The real roots are $\zeta_{6}^{3}$ and $\zeta_{6}^{6}$. Thank you +1.